# Replace value in one data frame from another

Tags: r

I've got two `data.frames`:

First:

```
   > dput(head(tbl_mz))
    structure(list(m.z = c(258.1686969, 258.168752, 587.8313625, 
    587.8425292, 523.2863282, 523.2859396), Measured.mass = c(514.3228408, 
    514.3229511, 1173.648172, 802.4706732, 1272.645144, 1044.557326
    )), .Names = c("m.z", "Measured.mass"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Second:

```
> dput(head(tbl_exl))
structure(list(V1 = c(802.4706732, 1272.649209, 1272.646875, 
1272.646599, 1272.646521, 1272.645144), V2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), V3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V6 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Positive"), class = "factor"), 
    V7 = c(28.7, 29.4, 29.4, 23.8, 28.6, 23.3), V8 = c(30.7, 
    31.4, 31.4, 25.8, 30.6, 25.3), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", 
"V7", "V8", "X", "X.1", "X.2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to replace some values from `tbl_exl`, column `V1` by values from the the other table `tbl_mz`. The values from column `V1` (tbl_exl) can be found in the column `Measured.mass` (tbl_mz) and they should be replaced by the values from the next column `m.z` in `tbl_mz` data frame.

In another words the values in the `V1` should be replaced by the `m.z` values.

The problem is that not all values from `V1` can't be find in the other data frame. Those which can be find can be deleted or just left like they are.

The output, which I want to get:

```
 > dput(head(tbl_exl_modified))
    structure(list(V1 = c(587.8425292, 1272.649209, 1272.646875, 
    1272.646599, 1272.646521, 523.2863282), V2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), V3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V6 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Positive"), class = "factor"), 
        V7 = c(28.7, 29.4, 29.4, 23.8, 28.6, 23.3), V8 = c(30.7, 
        31.4, 31.4, 25.8, 30.6, 25.3), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", 
    "V7", "V8", "X", "X.1", "X.2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `match`.  Create numeric indexes based on the `match` between the columns ("Measured.mass", "V1") of the two datasets.  Remove the `NA` values ("indx1", "indxN1") and replace the "V1" values to "m.z" based on these index.

```
indx <- match(tbl_mz$Measured.mass, tbl_exl$V1)
indx1 <- indx[!is.na(indx)]
indxN <-  match(tbl_exl$V1, tbl_mz$Measured.mass)
indxN1 <- indxN[!is.na(indxN)]
tbl_exl$V1[indx1] <- tbl_mz$m.z[indxN1]

identical(tbl_exl, tbl_exl_modified)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or use `left_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tbl_exl1 <- left_join(tbl_exl, tbl_mz, by=c('V1'='Measured.mass')) %>%
                mutate(V1= pmax((NA^!is.na(m.z))*V1, m.z,
                                                 na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
                select(-m.z)

 tbl_exl1
 #        V1 V2 V3 V4 V5       V6   V7   V8  X X.1 X.2
 #1  587.8425 NA NA NA NA Positive 28.7 30.7 NA  NA  NA
 #2 1272.6492 NA NA NA NA Positive 29.4 31.4 NA  NA  NA
 #3 1272.6469 NA NA NA NA Positive 29.4 31.4 NA  NA  NA
 #4 1272.6466 NA NA NA NA Positive 23.8 25.8 NA  NA  NA
 #5 1272.6465 NA NA NA NA Positive 28.6 30.6 NA  NA  NA
 #6  523.2863 NA NA NA NA Positive 23.3 25.3 NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `data.table`s binary join

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(tbl_exl), 1, "Measured.mass") # Changing the first column name for the join to work
setkey(tbl_exl, Measured.mass) # Keying tbl_exl by `Measured.mass`
setkey(setDT(tbl_mz), Measured.mass) # Keying tbl_exl by `Measured.mass`
tbl_exl[tbl_mz, Measured.mass := i.m.z][] # Joining and retrieving only matched values from `i.m.z`
#    Measured.mass V2 V3 V4 V5       V6   V7   V8  X X.1 X.2
# 1:      587.8425 NA NA NA NA Positive 28.7 30.7 NA  NA  NA
# 2:      523.2863 NA NA NA NA Positive 23.3 25.3 NA  NA  NA
# 3:     1272.6465 NA NA NA NA Positive 28.6 30.6 NA  NA  NA
# 4:     1272.6466 NA NA NA NA Positive 23.8 25.8 NA  NA  NA
# 5:     1272.6469 NA NA NA NA Positive 29.4 31.4 NA  NA  NA
# 6:     1272.6492 NA NA NA NA Positive 29.4 31.4 NA  NA  NA
```